# ¿Cómo hacer un select por número de columna en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, server

espero me puedan ayudar,

Tenemos una tabla que se actualiza diario mediante ETL y para mostrar un reporte con esa información se hace una llamada para obtener la info de la tabla, y se deberá mostrar con 3 filtros: a 3, 6 y 9 meses.

El problema es que los nombres de las columnas de los meses van cambiando, siempre se actualiza iniciando con el mes en curso, por ejemplo los campos actuales son:
Poliza, Nombre, PagoInicial, Oct, Nov, Dic, Enero, Feb, etc...

Como el nombre de columna se actualiza cada mes, se me ocurría por ejemplo con el filtro de 3 meses activado que solo hiciera algo así como especificar el número de columna:

"select Poliza, Nombre, PagoInicial, [column3], [column4], [column5] from Next_Payments;"

algo así, pero no sé cómo hacer una selección del número de columna en SQL Server, espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no nos serviría usar el nombre de columna por lo que les mencioné que cambia dependiendo del mes.

Comment: Lo mejor sería corregir el diseño de esa tabla. La estructura de las tablas no debería de cambiar de forma diaria.

Comment: Coincido con @LuisCazares . En lugar de incrementar el número de columnas en la tabla deberías insertar un nuevo registro cada vez que sea necesario. De esta forma es mucho más fácil sacar reportes.

Comment: Puedes hacer una consulta dinámica pero primero deberías "calcular" las columnas que quieres seleccionar, pero realmente no vale la pena si sigues la recomendación de Luis.